# Docker Error response from daemon: Ports are not available - Mac

Tags: docker, laravel-sail

I am trying to get Docker/LaravelSail via Mac to function. When starting up Docker I receive the error

`Attaching to flow-laravel.test-1, flow-mysql-1 Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:80 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use`

I understand the 80 port is being used elsewhere, but I am having difficulty trying to solve this. When I run `docker ps` I get the mySql container ID which is functioning.

On the docker dashboard I can see the followng[image: Docker Dashboard]

I tried manually stopping and starting the laravel-test1 container but had no luck.

My question is, how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After an exhausting search, I came across a video which added this line of code to the .env file

```
APP_PORT=89
```

By adding the line above the error is now resolved. Also migrated my database without issue.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. Solved my error as well

Comment: Great!! Happy it solved your issue as well!